# Audio voice message "Network connection failure"

Tags: windows-10

Each time I boot Win 10 or wake it up from sleep an annoying voice message is heard saying "Network connection failure." It's a female voice with a British accent. This is followed by the same voice saying "Internet connection established."

How do I get rid of this?

I thought it may have come from Skype, but Task Manager does not show Skype running nor is it in the Start up list?

Please tell me how to determine which program is generating this annoying voice.

Thanks!

Comment: I just realized that I recently installed TeamViewer. I wonder if it's coming from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Network Monitor II gadget from [nes.bplaced.net/sidebar7.html](http://nes.bplaced.net/sidebar7.html).  unchecked all four boxes about sounds on the #4 tab under Network Monitor II Options.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I deactivated alert messages and rebooted. Still got the message. I uninstalled TeamViewer and re-booted. Still got the message. I guess that's not the offending program. Could it be Cortana taskbar tidbits? I turned this option off.

Comment: Yep. Looks like it was Cortana. After turning off taskbar tidbits I put my machine to sleep then woke it up. No annoying voice! By the way, does Cortana have a female voice with a British accent?

Comment: Update: It was not Cortana. I got the voice again just now when I woke my machine up from sleep.

Comment: It may have been the Network Monitor II gadget. I'll have to do more testing.

Comment: Confirmed. It was Network Monitor II gadget from http://nes.bplaced.net/sidebar7.html. I unchecked all four boxes about sounds on the #4 tab under Network Monitor II Options. Please update your answer with this so we can close this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Done. :) Answer updated.